# Index and Match but for SQL

Tags: ms-access

I was wondering if it's possible to do an index and match query but for SQL, and I'm not quite sure how to simply google it myself.

But an example would be two tables like so

```
Date  ItemNumber  Location Code

x         1         MyHouse    90
y         2         YourHouse  100
z         3         OurHouse   200
```

and

```
column integers represent itemnumbers

Code  1   2   3   4  5   6   7  8  9
 90   MyHouse  MyHouse  MyHouse  MyHouse  OurHouse
100     Ourhouse   OurHouse  YourHouse  YourHouse
200  MyHouse  OurHouse  YourHouse  MyHouse YourHouse
```

After executing query, it should look something like

```
Date  ItemNumber  Location Code   PerfectDistance

x         1         MyHouse    90        MyHouse
y         2         YourHouse  100       MyHouse
z         3         OurHouse   200       YourHouse
```

or something to that affect, where you index and match on the code and item number like you would in excel.

Not looking for full solution, just a function idea.

Comment: You should normalize your 2nd table (each item should be 1 row), then the task becomes trivial.

Comment: Are you saying to transpose?

Comment: Rather, unpivot. The table should have 3 columns: Code, ItemNumber, Item. Then you can easily join however you want.

Comment: Oh, and: use http://ozh.github.io/ascii-tables/ to format your data. You can copy&paste from Excel or Access datasheet to "Input".

Answer (score 0):

[**`JOIN`**](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp) is what you're looking for.

Similar to Excel: `index(return_value, match(lookup_item, lookup_range, 0))` the **0** represents an `exact` match. You need an `exact` match for the `join` to work

Comment: I'm fiddling with it, but I also assume a subquery to get that 4th column?

Comment: To get the 4th column, a `Left Join` will work. 

Something like: `SELECT A.Date, A.ItemNumber , A.Location , A.Code ,
FROM A
LEFT JOIN B
ON B.Code = A.Code`

Based on the data you provided, it's difficult for me to create an exact query, but I hope this helped

https://www.guru99.com/joins.html -- This may also help :)

Comment: There's some funny business with how the data is formatted, I'll update this if I can ever get it formatted properly and let you know if this works.

Answer (score 0):

You must join the tables and use the function [`choose()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/choose-function-76230415-910f-463a-a799-cf7e90aa7fd4):

```
select t1.*,
  choose(t1.itemnumber, t2.[1], t2.[2], t2.[3], t2.[4], t2.[5], t2.[6], t2.[7], t2.[8], t2.[9]) as PerfectDistance
from table1 as t1 inner join table2 as t2
on t2.Code = t1.Code
```

For this `table1`:

```
Date    ItemNumber  Location    Code
x       1           MyHouse     90
y       2           YourHouse   100
z       3           OurHouse    200
```

and this `table2`:

```
Code    1        2          3         4         5           6   7   8   9
90      MyHouse  MyHouse    MyHouse   MyHouse   OurHouse                
100     OurHouse OurHouse   YourHouse                       
200     MyHouse  OurHouse   YourHouse MyHouse   YourHouse
```

the results are:

```
Date    ItemNumber  Location    Code    PerfectDistance
x       1           MyHouse     90      MyHouse
y       2           YourHouse   100     OurHouse
z       3           OurHouse    200     YourHouse
```

Comment: I'm certain this would work if I didn't have 100 item numbers to choose from (Something about it being too complex), or it might work better in DBeaver. I'll give that shot and let you know.

Comment: Which database do you use? This code is for MS Access.

Comment: This is access, but since I have over 100 items, it's stating that it's too complex to handle it. But even when I trimmed it down to just 4, it gave back empty values. Still playing with it.

Comment: @bosois check the results that I get.